# How to find coordinates on a circle that are theta degrees away?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

given:

- cx,cy - coordinates of the center of a circle
- x, y - coordinates on a circle
- theta - number of degrees

How do you find cooridnates x',y' that are theta degrees away from x,y on the circle?

Comment: @coffeemath:  you can get that from $x,y$ and the center.

Answer (score 1):

1. Redefine $X = x - c_x$ and $Y = y - c_y$.
2. Calculate your starting angle as $\phi = \tan^{-1}(Y/X)$. (Watch the quadrant.)
3. Calculate the radius of the circle using $r = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$.
4. Calculate your new $X'$ and $Y'$ as $X' = r \cos(\phi + \theta)$ and $Y' = r \sin(\phi + \theta)$.
5. Convert back: $x' = X' + c_x$ and $y' = Y' + c_y$.